# Unable to drop database due to illegal character

Tags: mysql, sql-drop

How can i drop a database containing the "-" symbol?

```
mysql> show databases;
+--------------------+
| Database           |
+--------------------+
| information_schema |
| mysql              |
| vms01              |
| vms-0.1.0          |
+--------------------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> drop database vms-0.1.0;
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that 
corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use n
    ear '-0.1.0' at line 1
    mysql>
```

Answer (score 42, accepted):

You can quote identifiers (for example table and column names) with backticks:

```
drop database `vms-0.1.0`
```

See the documentation for more details: [Schema Object Names](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/identifiers.html).

> The identifier quote character is the backtick ("`"):